# MyPy error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[X, Y]", expected "X")

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have 2 functions `func_1` and `func_2`. `func_1` expects type X to be returned while `func_2` expects `Union[X, Y]` to be returned.

```
from typing import Union

def func_2(...) -> Union[X, Y]:
    ...

def func_1(...) -> X:
    return func_2(...)
```

When we use MyPy on this code snippet, we will find it reporting the following:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Union[X, Y]", expected "X")
```

Note that `func_2` has to return one of 2 types, and the only way around it is to split it into 2 different functions, that do the same thing but each returns a single type. I want to avoid this if possible.

Why is this error thrown by MyPy? How can I overcome it without repeating myself?

Comment: What if `func_2` returns an instance of `Y`?

Comment: Yeah that would be a problem then, but how can we overcome this ?

Comment: That depends on a lot of details you haven't shown us.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica can you suggest some of the details that I can include to make the question clearer ? I was trying to make it to the point as possible.

Comment: We would need to know how the output type of `func_2` depends on the inputs, and what inputs `func_1` is passing it. Maybe `func_2` needs more specific type annotations. Maybe `func_1` is just fundamentally broken and mypy has successfully brought that to your attention.